# " import telegram.ext ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.ext'; 'telegram' is not a package" after installing python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot, python-3.11

Hey I was trying to edit a telegram bot, but this error keeps coming:
`import telegram.ext ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.ext'; 'telegram' is not a package`.

My code is like this:-

```
import telegram.ext

with open('token.txt', 'r') as f:
    TOKEN = f.read()


def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Helllo")


updater = telegram.ext.Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
disp = updater.dispatcher
```

any help will be appreciated

I've tried reinstalling python-telegram-bot.

Comment: Make sure that you have actuall installed the `python-telgeram-bot` library and that you're running your script from the same (virtual) python environment that you installed it to. Also make sure that you have no file or directory named "telegram"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've installed a wrong telegram package, too. Some IDEs install packages automatically and they install [telegram](https://pypi.org/project/telegram/) instead of [python-telegram-bot](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/).

You should find the wrong installed package and uninstall it.

Figure out what package is imported on `import telegram.ext`, you can find it in the error description. Then you should uninstall it, using a command like this:

```
pip uninstall telegam
```

Then install `python-telegram-bot` if it is not installed:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```